# Is there a way to create a time limit that will cause a pygame to close once it has reached the time?

Tags: pygame

I have been trying to create a PyGame, in which the users goal is to pop as many balloons as possible in a certain time frame. Before my game gets initiated I ask the user what difficulty they would like to play on then use their input to work out a time limit. However I have struggled with getting this time limit to work. Any help would be amazing.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

set a userevent and have it added to the event queue every 1000 ms (1 second.)

```
one_second_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
```

add it to the timer in init:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(one_second_event, 1000)
```

test for it in the event check

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.one_second_event:
       self.total_time += 1
```

you can then test total time against the time limit and quit when it is equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#[...]
time_limit = 6000 #6000 ms
while True:
    time_limit -= clock.tick(60) #Roughly 6 seconds
    if time_limit <= 0:
        #[...] Do whatever you want here
```